# Powershell script to open a number of files located inside subdirectories

Tags: command-line, powershell

How does one open (say, using notepad.exe) multiple files ending in _dc.txt, each one of which is located in a number of subdirectories of C:\Data\Test?

My script below gets stuck on -Recurse, with the error "Invoke-Item: A parameter cannot be found that matches the parameter name Recurse."

```
# recursively go into dc1 subfolders and open _dc.txt files
Clear-Host
$Directory = "C:\Data\Test*"

Invoke-Item -Path $Directory -Recurse -Include *_dc.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Recurse` is not one of the PowerShell "Common Parameters". Therefore, it is not available on all cmdlets. If you need the functionality of `-Recurse` for use with a cmdlet that doesn't support it, you'll need to pipe output from a cmdlet that does support it.

In this case, it looks like you'll also need to pass the output through a filtering cmdlet (like `Where-Object`) first. I tried using `-Include` with `Invoke-Item` but couldn't get it to behave like you want it.

Example:

```
Get-Childitem 'C:\Data\Test*' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "_dc.txt$"} | Invoke-Item
```

Expanded, with comments:

```
# Recursively search folders with names beginning 'C:\Data\Test' and return the objects found.
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Data\Test*' -Recurse |

# Filter objects to only those with names ending in `_dc.txt`.
Where-Object {$_.Name -match "_dc.txt$"} |

# Perform the default action (for .txt files, this is normally "Open with Notepad") on the objects.
Invoke-Item
```

Golfed:

```
ls 'C:\Data\Test*' -R|?{$_.Name -match "_dc.txt$"}|ii
```

- `ls` is a built-in alias for `Get-ChildItem`
- `-Recurse` can be trimmed to just `-R` since it's the only parameter with a name beginning with "R" for `Get-ChildItem`.
- `?` is a built-in alias for `Where-Object`.
- `ii` is a built-in alias for `Invoke-Item`.

Comment: I think this is a great answer - not only did you answer my question well but you explain other things which help me as I learn my way through ps.

Comment: @val I also suggest you try using PowerShell's built-in help functionality whenever you're having trouble with a command. The cmdlet is `Get-Help`. (Example: `Get-Help Invoke-Item`) Depending on what version of PowerShell you're using, you may need to `Update-Help` first.