# using powershell to open multiple txt files in directory

Tags: windows, powershell

i am trying to open 20+ .txt files in a directory.
i navigate the shell into the directory and tried to issue the following commands but they fail:

1. `./*.txt`
   //however t6.txt is a file in the directory and the command ./t6.txt works to open the single file
2. `notepad.exe Get-ChildItem .\*.txt` since notepad.exe .\t6.txt works i tried this
3. `notepad.exe | Get-ChildItem *.txt` opens an untitled blank notepad instance?!

i have found some really great answers that provide solutions [including this one](https://superuser.com/questions/815680/powershell-script-to-open-a-number-of-files-located-inside-subdirectories)!

i think i have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the shell works underneath the hood.
i am a lot surprised that i couldn't find this question elsewhere.
i think that explanations to how these statement are dumb/stupid/bad may provide the context necessary for me to interpret the documentation properly and un-!#@$ my thinking. thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will want a script like this:

```
get-childitem *.txt |foreach-object {
    notepad $_.name
}
```

This basically pipes the result object from a query for all txt files into the foreach-object, which then iterates through the resultset name by name and executes a command.

Comment: Or let the shell handle opening the file like `gci *.txt | % {. $_.fullname}`. That would allow for other file types to. *Note that I never felt a need to open 20 files at once in 20 different processes so I doubt the usefullness. It would be faster to just select the 20 files, right click, open imo*

Comment: yeah, i used to just right click and open but windows wont allow that anymore for some reason

Comment: I believe there's a limit to prevent users opening hundreds of files by accident but no doubt, that limit can be increased.

Comment: [MultipleInvokePromptMinimum](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-open-more-than-15-files-at-once-from-context-menu-in-windows) under `KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` apparently.

Comment: yeah, i just thought of that right as you posted it....it will let me open 15 at the moment. probably memory usage dependent?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish the same, especially in powershell. I love this method because it is fool proof and can easily be expanded to do way more. Great if you know this script by hand so you can use it in the future to do more stuff, like if comparisons etc.